# What should I write in ofSystem() of OFX?

Tags: terminal, youtube, openframeworks, youtube-dl

I am a mac users, I want to use youtube api to allow openframeworks load videos of youtube. So I use youtube-dl to download video in terminal. Then I found I can use ofSystem in OFX to execute terminal command. 
My problem is I can execute youtube-dl in terminal that it does download video from youtube, but when I write this command into OFX, it just said that  youtube-dl: command not found. 
My code :

```
     string link = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPMeEfeBcPU;
     string cmd = "youtube-dl " + link;
     cout<<ofSystem(cmd.c_str());
```

Actually, when I just transfer this command into a normal terminal command like

```
  string cmd = say Hello World!
```

This is works!

So I want to know what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the `youtube-dl`command with its full path. Something like:

```
string cmd = "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl " + link;
```

Some more detail:

The ofSystem() will most likely call system() internally, which starts the command-argument in sh and not in the bash you are using in your terminal.

To verify this, open terminal and call sh. This will open a new shell prompt (sh shell). Now call `youtube-dl` and it will most likely not be found as well.